# How to make wildcards take effect when to mount mobile phone with sshfs?

Tags: wildcard, mount, termux, sshfs

The wildcard '*' means it will match any number of characters or a set of characters.
`test*` matched `test.rst`,it works :

```
ls   /tmp/material/test*
/tmp/material/test.rst
```

Prepare my mobile phone to be mounted:

```
#download termux.apk and install on the mobile phone first,
#then do the following in termux console
pkg install openssh  
whoami
uo_a313
ifconfig
192.168.31.130

pkg install termux-auth
passed  #set password

sshd  #start ssh server in the mobile phone
termux-setup-storage
```

Now i can mount the mobile phone:

```
sudo sshfs -p 8022 u0_a313@192.168.31.130://data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/downloads/WeiXin    /mnt/material
sudo ls  /mnt/material
test.rst
sudo ls  /mnt/material/test*
ls: cannot access '/mnt/material/test*': No such file or directory
```

[image]

How to make `*` match any number of characters as usual when to mount mobile pjone with sshfs ?